# Why the clique numbers of almost all graphs are concentrated at two values?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, probabilistic-method

I read that for fixed $0\leq p \leq 1$, the clique number of $G(n, p)$ is concentrated at $d$ and $d+1$, where $d$~$2log_{\frac{1}{p}}n$.

The key point is that $d$ is the maximum integer with $\binom{n}{d}p^{\binom{d}{2}}\geq ln(n)$.

Is there any simple proof?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Paul Hudford's answer thought that the question is about the chromatic number, whereas the question is about the **clique number** of the random graph. Another inaccuracy with Paul's answer (although it has nothing to do with the question asked) is that in the paper being referred to, Heckel proves anti-concentration for intervals of length $\sim n^{1/4}$ (not $\sim n^{1/2}$), but recently in joint work with Riordan, Heckel announced a proof of an optimal bound of the form $\sim n^{1/2}$: https://www.math.princeton.edu/events/non-concentration-chromatic-number-random-graph-2019-11-06t200000

**To answer the original question**, it is important to realize that when a statement is made about almost all graphs, the object in question is $G(n,1/2)$, as opposed to $G(n,p)$ where $p$ is a parameter that shrinks with $n$. When $p$ is some other value that is constant, usually the situation is similar.

Something that is true is the following: $G(n,1/2)$ with high probability has its clique number to be one of two special values, and these values are near $2\log(n)$. The intuition is as follows:

Let $X_k$ be the random variable counting the number of $k$-cliques in $G(n,1/2)$. If $\mathbb{E}(X_k)\to 0$, by Markov's inequality, $G$ almost surely does not contain a $k$-clique. If $\mathbb{E}(X_k)\to \infty$ on the other hand, calculating the variance will reveal that almost surely $G$ almost surely contains a $k$-clique. What needs to be true for two-point-concentration to hold is that $\mathbb{E}[X_k]$ has a *phase shift* that occurs around $k\sim2\log(n)$.

You can calculate that the ratio $\frac{\mathbb{E}[X_{k+1}]}{\mathbb{E}[X_{k}]}=o(1)$ when $k$ is close to $2\log(n)$. What this means is that $\mathbb{E}[X_k]$ cannot stay some constant value for more than a couple of values of $k$. Say for example that $\mathbb{E}[X_k]\sim 10$ for some special value of $k$ (near $2\log(n)$). Then, the result about the ratio I'm referring to shows that $\mathbb{E}[X_{k+1}]\to 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_{k-1}]\to \infty$, which already gives a **three**-point-concentration result.

For more details, I suggest Zhao's notes available here (pages 34-35): https://yufeizhao.com/pm/probmethod_notes.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I can roughly understand your thoughts and the material you provided is very helpful!!!